# time reset at specified hour daily

Tags: java, time

I want to trigger an event at 5:00 am everyday. And I want to implement it in player's heartbeat. Our design is to have a heartbeat every minute.

```
    @Override
    public void playerHeart(Player player, long time) {
        Reset reset = player.getBase().getReset();
        if (!TimeUtil.isSameDay(reset.getResetTime(), time)) {
            EventManager.fire(EventOnPlayerDailyReset.class, e -> e.onPlayerDailyReset(player));
            if (time >= TimeUtil.getClockTime(time, 3600 * 5)) {
                EventManager.fire(EventOnDailyAtHour5.class, e -> e.onDailyAtHour5(player));
            }
            reset.setResetTime(time);
            player.saveBase();
        }

        // to be implemented: judge if now mills is around 5:00 am and trigger EventOnDailyAtHour5


        EventManager.fire(EventOnPlayerHeart.class, e -> e.onPlayerHeart(player, time));
    }

    @Data
    public class Reset {

        @Tag(1)
        private long resetTime;

    }
```

My question is, how to trigger only one event around 5 o'clock each day?

Should I add a boolean field let's call `resetAt5` in `Reset` class to mark I triggered `EventOnDailyAtHour5` today to avoid repeated triggering?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add a boolean field `resetAt5` in Reset class.

```
public void playerHeart(Player player, long time) {
    Reset reset = player.getBase().getReset();
    if (!TimeUtil.isSameDay(reset.getResetTime(), time)) {
        EventManager.fire(EventOnPlayerDailyReset.class, e -> e.onPlayerDailyReset(player));

        reset.setResetAt5(false);
        if (time >= TimeUtil.getClockTime(time, 3600 * 5)) {
            EventManager.fire(EventOnPlayerResetAtHour5.class, e -> e.onPlayerResetAtHour5(player));
            reset.setResetAt5(true);
        }
        reset.setResetTime(time);
        player.saveBase();
    }

    if (!reset.isResetAt5() && time >= TimeUtil.getClockTime(time, 3600 * 5)) {
        EventManager.fire(EventOnPlayerResetAtHour5.class, e -> e.onPlayerResetAtHour5(player));
        reset.setResetAt5(true);
        player.saveBase();
    }

    EventManager.fire(EventOnPlayerHeart.class, e -> e.onPlayerHeart(player, time));
}

@Data
public class Reset {

    @Tag(1)
    private long resetTime;

    @Tag(2)
    private boolean resetAt5;
}
```